# Why GoEthereum blockchain nodes sync under one day

Tags: ethereum, blockchain, go-ethereum

Hey blockchain enthusiasts, is their any improvement in eth syncing after the latest version update cause previously it was taking 1 week and now it's taking just a day to download the entire blockchain data.

I tries it a few days ago but there it took a lot of time but now its taking only a half day. I want to understand what is the new change in it?

Answer (score 0):

GoEthereum features [snap sync](https://geth.ethereum.org/docs/interface/sync-modes).

Snap sync is on by default for recent GoEthereum versions.